# WPF binding for DataGridCheckBoxColumn not updating

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to figure out how to correctly handle the `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`. I have a list of data that includes a 'Publish' option. When checked the object is flagged to be published to a different server. 
So far here is what I have:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grdEducationalPopups" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Margin="19,155,0,0"                   
              AlternationCount="2"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding PopupCollection}"
              Loaded="grdEducationalPopups_Loaded"
              MinRowHeight="26"
              RowDetailsTemplate="{StaticResource RowDetailTemplate}" RowDetailsVisibilityChanged="grdEducationalPopups_RowDetailsVisibilityChanged" SelectionChanged="grdEducationalPopups_SelectionChanged" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">           
        <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ToggleButton x:Name="RowHeaderToggleButton" Click="ToggleButton_Click" Cursor="Hand"/>                    
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        <DataGrid.Columns>                
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="150" Binding="{Binding DisplayName}" Header="Form Name" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="280" Binding="{Binding URLLocation}" Header="Page Address"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="125" Binding="{Binding DateLastTouched}" Header="Date Modified" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="125" Binding="{Binding DateRowAdded}" Header="Date Added" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Publish" Binding="{Binding Path=Publish}">
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Checked" Handler="OnChecked"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I do have OnClick code but it is not doing anything right now except for allowing me to check the values. The value within my list for publish does not change. The publish value for the given record remains `false` when it should be true. 
If I change the default value from false to true and launch my application, then all checkboxes are checked, which is what I would expect. This tells me that my binding is correct.

How do I correctly manage user changes so that I can act on the changes appropriately? In my code behind I get a DataGridCell object back and can determine the row data from there, and I suppose edit that data. But I was under the impression that Binding the data should handle this.

Comment: Assuming that your "Publish"-option is a boolean property you should react to changes of that property in a PropertyChangeEvent instead of using the OnChecked event. Set up a PropertyChange Listener for the items of your PopupCollection, e.g. in your ViewModel or whereever you need it. If the event fires and the property name is"Publish" you can perform the according publish actions.

Comment: Thanks for all of the replies. The core of my problem is that I am not implementing the data binding correctly. I have a code behind method that is setting the item source at runtime and my implementation of this is the core of the problem.

Answer (score 14):

There is nothing wrong with your code. It's just that the value is not immediately updated, only after the `ComboBox` loses its focus.

You can change that by setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the binding.

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Publish" Binding="{Binding Path=Publish, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer not to work with bode behind but manage this in the ViewModel. I didn't execute your code now, but first of all, I would configure the Binding of the CheckBoxColumn like

```
Binding="{Binding Path=Publish, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

In the setter of the Publish property, you can write your business logic. If it's very time consuming (access to network often is), I also recommend to do it asynchroneously.

I could provide a simple example if you want. But there should be plenty already in other threads.